# Function that evaluates any ( ... -> IO () ) function

Tags: haskell, lambda

**I have** several functions in main that output information.

**I need** to measure their execution time.

Currently it's done like this:

```
  start <- getCurrentTime
  putStrLn $ show $ findNthMinLinear (getTestArrayOfLength (read arrlength :: Int)) 4
  stop <- getCurrentTime
  print $ diffUTCTime stop start
```

I want to wrap each function in a function that 1. remembers the time 2. evaluates function 3. remembers the time 4. prints difference between two remembered times

**The problem** is that i don't know how to pass a function without evaluating it first.

**My guess** is that if i write (<5) for example, that is i create a function that returns a function, no real work will be done until i pass final parameter i guess? 
Then i could write

```
printAndMeasure :: (a -> IO()) -> IO ()
...
printAndMeasure \x -> (getTestArrayOfLength (read arrlength :: Int)) 4
```

but it's a sloppy solution because i don't really need this x other than to hold function from being executed.

Comment: You should probably use [Criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/criterion/latest/doc/html/Criterion-Main.html) for benchmarking.

Comment: What gave you the impression that passing a function evaluates it? That happens in no language with first-class functions, and most certainly not in lazy Haskell. Anyway, you're not even talking about functions here but about _monadic `IO` actions_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing a function does not evaluate it. So you can have function like `IO () -> IO ()` and pass `IO` actions to them. When a program is run only `main` function is executed and arguments of a function are not evaluated until needed (laziness).
If you are trying to benchmark your code then it is better to use benchmarking libraries like `Criterion`.